# How to find an error log from a lambda function by request id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

Suppose i have a lambda function and i have a permission error.
[image]

How am i supposed to find this error by the request id? The request id is not in the log. Should i search for the timestamp and then guess or is there a better way?